# Unable to uninstall Matlab

Tags: matlab, software-uninstall

I encountered the following errors while attempting to uninstall Matlab on Ubuntu:

```
fayo@fayo-pc:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a ; sudo apt-get purge -y 
Setting up matlab-support (0.0.19) ...
No default Matlab path found. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package matlab-support (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 matlab-support
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 353 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up matlab-support (0.0.19) ...
No default Matlab path found. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package matlab-support (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 matlab-support
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it depends on how you installed it (and you do not tell us that) "No default Matlab path found. Exiting." Probably not with "apt-get"..

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get purge matlab`?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda `Package 'matlab' has no installation candidate`, therefore a `purge` would not work.

Comment: Close-voters, what's unclear. `matlab-support` is in the repositories and can removed in the standard way.

Answer (score 1):

Forget the command `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, you don't have mathlab installed.

Use only the command

```
sudo apt-get purge matlab-support
```

to remove the package.