# How to uninstall MATLAB

Tags: uninstall, matlab

So I've looked around how to do this but so far haven't had luck.  I've tried [the command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654259/unable-to-uninstall-matlab)

sudo apt-get purge matlab-support

And then I tried [this one](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102428-how-do-i-uninstall-matlab-products-on-a-unix-or-linux-machine), but I don't have a folder "lmdown".  I try just

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/MATLAB/2019b

But that doesn't remove it.  How do I get rid of it?  It's taking up a lot of space (it was giving me issues, so I downloaded it twice... now it's quite annoying).

Comment: How you uninstall software depends entirely upon how you originally installed it. There is no magic incantation for trouble-free uninstall.

Comment: I know there isn't one, but I'm wondering what the commands are to do it.  As far as I'm aware, it was a fairly normal installation.  Just followed the installer or whatever instructions there was, and tried to do the most normal installation, along with some packages I selected. @user535733

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a "normal" installation. I think you might mean "a bunch of debian packages using apt"...but maybe you consider normal to be something else. If deb packages, then use `dpkg -l | grep matlab` to see which packages with 'matlab' in the name you have in your package database.

Comment: "dpkg -l | grep matlab" didn't return anything, but with "dpkg -l grep matlab" I got "dpkg-query: no packages found matching matlab".

Comment: What I did looked something like this: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-matlab-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: There are no deb packages installed in that linked instruction. So apt would indeed have nothing installed, and apt-get removal would do nothing. Matlab apparently does not do a normal-for-Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the directory where you installed matlab.
The default is /usr/local/MATLAB

If matlab is still in your path, you should be able to find it.

```
which matlab
```

might give you `/usr/bin/matlab`
then use

```
ls -l /usr/bin/matlab
```

to find where the real location is.